# Solving Recurrence Solve $\ T(n)= n^2/2* T(n/2)+n^4/8*T(n/4),T(1)=T(2)=1 $

Tags: recurrence-relations

Well... I've tried hard...

The problem is 
Solve  $\ T(n)= n^2/2* T(n/2)+n^4/8*T(n/4),T(1)=T(2)=1  $ 
for all values of n that is a power of 2.

Actually, I do only know that I can let $\ n=2^m$
...However, I have no idea than:(

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2^m$ and $a_m=T(2^m).$ Then
$$
a_m = 2^{2m-1}a_{m-1}+2^{4m-3}a_{m-2} \;\;,\;\; a_0 = 1,\;a_1=1
$$
When we calculate the first few elements $a_0,a_1,\ldots,$ it appears as if $a_m=2^{m^2-1}b_m$ with a suitable sequence $b_0,b_1,\ldots$

When we perform this substitution, we get
$$
2^{m^2-1}b_m = 2^{2m-1}2^{(m-1)^2-1}b_{m-1}+2^{4m-3}2^{(m-2)^2-1}b_{m-2} \;\;,\;\; b_0 = 2,\;b_1=1
$$
or
$$
2^{m^2-1}b_m = 2^{m^2-1}b_{m-1}+2^{m^2}b_{m-2}\;\;,\;\; b_0 = 2,\;b_1=1
$$
or
$$
b_m = b_{m-1}+2b_{m-2}\;\;,\;\; b_0 = 2,\;b_1=1
$$
This is an ordinary homogeneous [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation), which is equivalent to
$$
b_m = 2^m+(-1)^m
$$
Therefore,
$$
T(2^m)=a_m=2^{m^2-1}b_m = 2^{m^2-1}\left(2^m+(-1)^m\right)
$$